# mvn test throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am trying to run cucumber+testNG+selenium through Maven .

My Runner File looks like this

```
//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    format={"pretty", "json:target/report.json"},
    features = {"classpath:cucumber/sample.feature"},               
    glue = "com.stepDefinitions",
    tags="@test"        
    )
public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests { 

}
```

I initialize my driver in @BeforeSuite

```
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

It works fine when i run it through **TestNG Test** in Eclipse , But it throws Null Pointer Exception while i try it with **mvn test**

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Do you have any error message? Or warning? Maybe you can try with `mvn -X test` to enable traces and it may print some useful information

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your webdriver in @BeforeClass or @BeforeMethod

Because @BeforeSuite is run only in suite

Comment: i tested with @BeforeClass , Same issue appears .